# Variable empty with if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, each

```
$(".my-input").each(function () {
            var theSelectBoxContainer = $(this).parent().next();
            var theSelectBoxValue = theSelectBoxContainer.dxSelectBox('instance').option('value');

            var txtvalue = $(this).val();
            if (txtvalue != "" && txtvalue!=" ") {
                if (i)
                    field += " and ";
                field = field + "'" + $(this).val() + "'";                    
                i++;
            }
        });
```

Above my jQuery code. With this code, I overwrite the values entered in the TextBoxes. But I do not want textboxes to be written when null characters are entered. But it is written. I check with if, but it is not. Where is the error?

Comment: simple use with  `if(txtvalue.trim())` its validate `null,undefined and empty`

Comment: `if (txtValue.trim())`

Comment: if(txtvalue.trim()) is working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.trim(txtvalue)` which will validate empty, null and undefined.

Or you can also use:

```
if (txtvalue === undefined || txtvalue === null) {
    // show error messages..
} else {
    //execute this code..
}
```